# How can I read the header but also skip lines - read.table()?

Tags: r, header, skip, read.table, read.csv

Data.txt:

```
Index;Time;
1;2345;
2;1423;
3;5123;
```

The code:

```
dat <- read.table('data.txt', skip = 1, nrows = 2, header =TRUE, sep =';')
```

The result:

```
  X1 X2345
1  2  1423
2  3  5123
```

I expect the header to be Index and Time, as follows:

```
  Index Time
1   2   1423
2   3   5123
```

How do I do that?

Comment: probably duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860071/read-csv-skip-second-line

Comment: @DavidArenburg indeed is the accepted answer you linked the probably best approach

Comment: Have you looked into doing a combination of head() and tail() functions? It might get pretty nested based on how deep you're going, but I believe this will give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I am afraid, that there is no direct way to achieve this. Either you read the entire table and remove afterwards the lines you don't want or you read in the table twice and assign the header later:

```
header <- read.table('data.txt', nrows = 1, header = FALSE, sep =';', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dat    <- read.table('data.txt', skip = 2, header = FALSE, sep =';')
colnames( dat ) <- unlist(header)
```

Comment: You need to put `, stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in your first line for this to work.

Comment: @Thomas I agree that this should be done, although I do not really see why it _has_ to be done. At least I do not have an example at hand where this would be necessary.

Comment: This code does not work with the OP's example file without it...at least not on my machine.

Comment: @Thomas you are right. The reason is (and I am sure you know that) that in the OP's example all lines end with a `;` giving a missing column and column names containing an `NA`. This indeed makes a problem when calling `unlist(header)`.

Comment: fwiw I used `as.is=T` instead of `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` and it seems to have worked just the same.

Answer (score 8):

You're using skip incorrectly.  Try this:

```
dat <- read.table('data.txt', nrows = 2, header =TRUE, sep =';')[-1, ]
```

Comment: That will work if I've got small data sets. But, say, I want to skip 600000 lines and get the first row as my column names. Your code will waste a lot of memory.

Comment: This still doesn't give the desired output for me, I get only
`Index 2 Time 1423`

Answer (score 3):

The solution using `fread` from `data.table`.

```
require(data.table)
fread("Data.txt", drop = "V3")[-1]
```

Result:

```
> fread("Data.txt", drop = "V3")[-1]
   Index Time
1:     2 1423
2:     3 5123
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `read.table()`, use a `readr` function such as `read_csv()`, piped to `dplyr::slice()`.

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
dat <- read_csv("data.txt") %>% slice(-1)
```

It's very fast too.

Comment: I just discovered this and have a similar situation. How does `readr`'s column specification work since the second row is a different format than the rest of the data? Is there a good way to assign the column types after importing the data?

Answer (score 2):

You could (in most cases), `sub` out the ending `;` write a new file without the second row (which is really the first row because of the header), and use `read.csv` instead of `read.table`

```
> txt <- "Index;Time;
  1;2345;
  2;1423;
  3;5123;" 
> writeLines(sub(";$", "", readLines(textConnection(txt))[-2]), 'newTxt.txt')
> read.csv('newTxt.txt', sep = ";")
##   Index Time
## 1     2 1423
## 2     3 5123
```

Comment: This is very inefficient for large files. I tried this recently, and it was very slow for some smaller files, but it never completed for larger ones.