# read csv, skip three lines but include header names in data.frame

Tags: r, csv

I want to read csv file skip three lines (except header) but include header names in data.frame. I've tried following but header names are wrong:

```
> sine = read.csv(file="sine.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",", skip=3, check.names=TRUE)
> colnames(sine)
 [1] "X0"     "X0.0"   "X0.0.1" "X0.0.2" "None"   "X1.0"   "X0.0.3" "None.1" "X.."   
[10] "X0.1"   "X0.2"
```

When I read dataset without skipping three lines header names are OK:

```
> sine = read.csv(file="sine.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",", skip=0, check.names=TRUE)
> colnames(sine)
 [1] "reset"                                                                                    
 [2] "angle"                                                                                    
 [3] "sine"                                                                                     
 [4] "multiStepPredictions.actual"                                                              
 [5] "multiStepPredictions.1"                                                                   
 [6] "anomalyScore"                                                                             
 [7] "multiStepBestPredictions.actual"                                                          
 [8] "multiStepBestPredictions.1"                                                               
 [9] "anomalyLabel"                                                                             
[10] "multiStepBestPredictions.multiStep.errorMetric..altMAPE..steps..1..window.1000.field.sine"
[11] "multiStepBestPredictions.multiStep.errorMetric..aae..steps..1..window.1000.field.sine"
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use header=TRUE, not head.

Comment: The solution, via the linked answer, is `read.csv("sine.csv", header = FALSE, skip = 4, col.names = names(read.csv("sine.csv", nrow = 0)))`.  The 4 is to allow for the header line being skipped as well.

Comment: @RichardScriven thank you this finally worked as expected

Comment: @RichardScriven please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: The solution in my comment came directly from the linked answer, so please go there and upvote MrFlick since he was the original poster.  He should get the credit for that.

Answer (score 3):

something like this,

```
foo <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/test.csv", header=T)
foo
#    make   model mpg weight price
# 1   amc concord  22   2930  4099
# 2   amc   oacer  17   3350  4749
# 3   amc  spirit  22   2640  3799
# 4 buick century  20   3250  4816
# 5 buick electra  15   4080  7827
colnames(foo)
# [1] "make"   "model"  "mpg"    "weight" "price" 

bar <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/test.csv", header=T, skip=3)
bar
#     amc  spirit X22 X2640 X3799
# 1 buick century  20  3250  4816
# 2 buick electra  15  4080  7827
colnames(bar)
# [1] "amc"    "spirit" "X22"    "X2640"  "X3799"
```

As [Richard Scriven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34621535/read-csv-skip-three-lines-but-include-header-names-in-data-frame/34621726#comment56989495_34621726) pointed out below my initial answer did not work, don't know how I missed that. Found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15860268/1305688) and made the solution below.

```
all_content = readLines("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/test.csv")
skip_second = all_content[c(c(-2:-4))]
foo2 = read.csv(textConnection(skip_second), 
                header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
foo2
#    make   model mpg weight price
# 1 buick century  20   3250  4816
# 2 buick electra  15   4080  7827
colnames(foo2)
# [1] "make"   "model"  "mpg"    "weight" "price"
```

Comment: Thank you I've upvoted but @RichardScriven solution seems more simple.

Comment: I agree Richard's solution is more elegant.

Comment: @WakanTanka, please post Richard Scriven's solution as an answer and have the question closed.