# How to import Qualtrics data (in csv format) into R

Tags: r, csv, import, tidyverse, qualtrics

I am trying to import a data downloaded from Qualtrics into R. It is a csv file.

[image]

However, I encounter 2 problems.

1. R could not figure out the format of each column by itself, probably because row 2 and row 3 (highlighted above) are all useless text. R thinks that all columns are `character`. However, obviously some are `date`, some are `factor`, and some are `integer`. How can R figure out the data class of each column correctly by itself?

> ```
> library(tidyverse)
> filename <- "mydata.csv"
> df = read_csv(filename, col_names = TRUE)
>
> Parsed with column specification:
> cols(
>   .default = col_character()
> )
> See spec(...) for full column specifications.
> ```

2. I also tried to load the variable name (`header`) and data matrix separately. Unfortunately, using the `skip = 3` argument does not work. It says that my data only has 1 observation... Why?

> ```
>  filename <- "mydata.csv"
>  headers = read_csv(filename, col_names = FALSE, n_max = 1)
>  df = read_csv(filename, skip = 3, col_names = FALSE)
>  colnames(df)= headers
> ```

```
Error in names(x) <- value : 
'names' attribute [273] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

What is a good way to import my csv file into R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following code to import data from Qualtrics into R:

```
library(tidyverse)
filename <- "mydata.csv"
headers = read_csv(filename, col_names = FALSE, n_max = 1)
df = read_csv(filename, skip = 3, col_names = FALSE)
colnames(df)= headers
```

However, there is one caveat. ***This method only works when you removed all line breaks when you downloaded your data.*** (Please see the graph below as to how to do so.) My `skip = 3` argument works because I removed all line breaks when I downloaded the data from Qualtrics. It is very probable that the questions you asked in Qualtrics contains multiple lines. It constitutes a problem for R to understand your file in this way. I recommend you to remove all line breaks when you download the data from the website.

Using the method above, R can normally correctly recognise the data structure of most columns, saving yourself a ton of effort to recode yourself.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the function read_survey from the package qualtRics. It has the additional advantage that it shortens some of the very long wordings in matrix questions. See also here: https://www.adrianbruegger.com/post/import-qualtrics-csv-files/