# How to merge many .csv files into R excluding the top three rows?

Tags: r, dataset

I made an experiment online, and the software gave me back a bunch of .csv files. I want to import them and merge them into one long data set. However, the software I used for the test added three rows with only seven columns (the participant id and the timestamp and other demographics) at the top, and I think that's what's not letting me import the files with all the columns.

I was trying this:

```
tbl<- list.files(pattern = "*csv") %>%
    map_df(~read.csv(.))
```

But it does not work because R just adds the first 7 columns and not the 16 I need. I'm adding a picture of one of the .csv files so you can see what I mean[image]

What I want is everything after column 4. I would love if I could add the demographics of the first rows since it's the participant number and their age, but if it's too difficult I would be happy with just the rows after the fourth one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can skip the first 3 rows using `skip` parameter of `read.cvs`. You could check `?read.cvs`. In case you need the data from the first rows as well, you could use two separate `read.cvs` commands, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110755/skip-specific-rows-using-read-csv-in-r).

P.S. Your question seems to be about programming in R and not about statistics, so I flagged it as off-topic to be moved to Stackoverflow.