# Reading in a multiindex .csv file as returned from pandas using the ftable type in R

Tags: python, r, pandas, csv

I have a multi-index (multi-column to be exact) pandas data frame in Python that I saved using the `.to_csv()` method. Now I would like to continue my analysis in R. For that I need to read in the `.csv` file. I know that R does not really support multi-index data frames like pandas does but it can handle ftables using the `stats` package. I tried to use `read.ftable()` but I can't figure out how to set the arguments right to correctly import the `.csv` file.

Here's some code to create a `.csv` file that has the same structure as my original data:

```r
require(stats)

# create example .csv file with a multiindex as it would be saved when using pandas
fileConn<-file('test.csv')
long_string = paste("col_level_1,a,b,c,d\ncol_level_2,cat,dog,tiger,lion\ncol_level_3,foo,foo,foo,foo\nrow_level_1,,,,\n1,",
                    "\"0,525640810622065\",\"0,293400380474675\",\"0,591895790442417\",\"0,675403394728461\"\n2,\"0,253176104907883\",",
                    "\"0,107715459748816\",\"0,211636325794272\",\"0,618270276545688\"\n3,\"0,781049927692169\",\"0,72968971635063\",",
                    "\"0,913378426593516\",\"0,739497259262532\"\n4,\"0,498966730971063\",\"0,395825713762063\",\"0,252543611974303\",",
                    "\"0,240732390893718\"\n5,\"0,204075522469035\",\"0,227454178487449\",\"0,476571725142606\",\"0,804041968683541\"\n6,",
                    "\"0,281453400066927\",\"0,010059089264751\",\"0,873336799707968\",\"0,730105129502755\"\n7,\"0,834572206714808\",",
                    "\"0,668889079581709\",\"0,516135581764696\",\"0,999861473609101\"\n8,\"0,301692961056344\",\"0,702428450077691\",",
                    "\"0,211660363912457\",\"0,626178589354395\"\n9,\"0,22051883447221\",\"0,934567760412661\",\"0,757627523007149\",",
                    "\"0,721590060307143\"",sep="")
writeLines(long_string, fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

When opening the `.csv` file in a reader of your choice, it should look like this:

[image]

How can I read this in using R?

Comment: Have you considered using `reticulate` instead of writing out the file to CSV and trying to read it back in? Not sure whether that'll solve the problem but that interface seems relatively seamless.

Comment: What are your anticipated column names, `a` or `a_cat_foo` (etc)?

Comment: Good question! Actually, both would be okay for me for now, since neither of those I can't get to work. Preferably the second option!

Comment: As long as `as.matrix(read.ftable(...)` gives me the right data matrix, I'm fine. Still, it would be nice though to somehow save the information from the multiindex columns and the index.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution **without** using `read.ftable()` [based on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39113320/8792159). Not that this won't give you the data in the `ftable` format:

```
headers <- read.csv(file='./test.csv',header=F,nrows=3,as.is=T,row.names=1)
dat <- read.table('./test.csv',skip=4,header=F,sep=',',row.names=1)
headers_collapsed <- apply(headers,2,paste,collapse='.')
colnames(dat) <- headers_collapsed
```