# dplyr : how to read a tsv file with headers while skipping some lines?

Tags: r, csv, data.table, dplyr, readr

I have a simple `tsv` file with the following structure:

```
0 - headerline
1 - empty line
2 - PIG schema
3 - empty line
4 - 1-st line of DATA
5 - 2-nd line of DATA
```

I would like to read it, possibly using `readr::read_tsv` but here is the problem.

As you can see, the first row contains the headers. Then I have three rows that I do **NOT** want to read it (they contains some super weird data coming from Apache PIG), and at row 4 the data starts. In `Pandas`, I would do something like

```
df = pd.read_csv('/localpath/data.tsv', sep='\t', skiprows=[1,2,3])
```

which allows me to read the headers **AND** to skip row one, two, three.

I don't see a similar option in `readr::read_tsv`. That is :

`df = read_tsv('/localpath/data.tsv', col_names = TRUE, skip = 4)`

which does not parse the headers...

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe read in the first row as a separate object, and then read in the remaining rows?

Comment: how would you code that? are there other alternatives with other packages? I want to reduce playing with the data as much as possible

Comment: use plain `read.table` ?

Comment: thanks @rawr but is there an option to skip these lines?

Comment: yes, also called `skip`

Comment: `names_t <- read.*sv(..., nrows = 1); df1 <- read.*sv(..., skip = 4, header = F); names(df1) <- names_t`?

Comment: @rawr it does not seem `skip` allows a list or rows though? `skip 
integer: the number of lines of the data file to skip before beginning to read data.`

Comment: yes that's true http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860071/read-csv-header-on-first-line-skip-second-line

Comment: thanks, but the solution provided there fails wiyh large data. I think i ll have to go with the two step processs...

Comment: @bouncyball do you mind posting your suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer. Basically, we read in the first row as our header, and then read in the remaining rows as the data:

```
library(readr)
names_t <- read_tsv('/localpath/data.tsv', col_names = FALSE, n_max = 1)
df1 <- read_tsv('/localpath/data.tsv', col_names = FALSE, skip = 4)
names(df1) <- names_t
```

Note that in my comment I specified `nrows = 1` to read in the names (this would work for `read.csv`), but it appears that this argument is replaced by `n_max` in `readr::read_tsv`.