# R: How to skip specific rows when using read.table on CSV file?

Tags: r

I have searched many fora, but still couldn't find a clear answer to my question: In R, how to skip specific rows when using read.table on a CSV file? For example, I have a CSV file with 4000 rows and I only want to read in the first 2000 files.

I know that with

> read.table(data, skip = 6)

the first lines can be skipped, but how can I skip all rows from 2001? And how can I skip a specific row, say row 1500?

Comment: This is answered here already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860071/read-csv-header-on-first-line-skip-second-line

Comment: Try `nrows` argument of `read.table`