# Skip rows while use read_excel or read.excel in R

Tags: r, xlsx, readxl

I have a excel file like this:

[image]

I try to read it in `read.xlsx` or `read_excel` by skipping the second row:

```
library(xlsx)
df <- read.xlsx('./data.xls', 'Sheet1')

library(readxl)
df <- read_excel("./data.xls", sheet = 'Sheet0', skip = 2, col_names = TRUE)
```

The first one (`read.xlsx`), I didn't find parameters for `skip` rows, the second one give a `df` without headers.

Where did I do wrong in the code above and how to read it correctly? Thanks.

Comment: I think you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860071/read-csv-header-on-first-line-skip-second-line

Comment: I'm not sure if we can read `.xlsx` file with `read_csv`, I get an error like this when I'm trying to do so: `line 1 appears to contain embedded nullsline 2 appears to contain embedded nullsline 3 appears to contain embedded nullsline 4 appears to contain embedded nullsline 5 appears to contain embedded nullsError in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : `

Comment: I see, you are right. I think zx8754's answer below would help. I would just read the excel as it is and then remove the second row.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Read it twice: once for column names, then for the data:

```
library(readxl)
myCols <- as.character(read_excel("./test123.xlsx", n_max = 1, col_names = FALSE))
myDF <- read_excel("./test123.xlsx", skip = 2, col_names = myCols)

myDF
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   colAtitle colBtitle
#       <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1         1         5
# 2         2         6
# 3         3         7
```

Example input: test123.xlsx

[image]