# Skip multiple header rows while using read_excel or read.excel in R

Tags: r, dataframe, xlsx, readxl

For an excel file with multiple row of headers as such **(test data for downloading from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/56y036hgbf5d70oh8qvpr/test_data_2022-03-29.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=76ssl651lz25k4ro96dtbsshh))**:

[image]

How could I skip rows `Unit` and `Frequency` and use `indicator_name` as header of excel file while reading excel with R?

With code below, it seems I could only skip one row by setting skip parameter an integer.

```
library(readxl)
myCols <- as.character(read_excel("./test123.xlsx", n_max = 1, col_names = FALSE))
myDF <- read_excel("./test123.xlsx", skip = 2, col_names = myCols)
```

Reference:

[Skip rows while use read_excel or read.excel in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62529816/skip-rows-while-use-read-excel-or-read-excel-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to `skip = 3` instead of 2, as you need to skip the header when you read in the data. Since we have already defined column names in `myCols`, then we do not need to keep the column name row when you read it in.

```
library(readxl)

myCols <- as.character(read_excel("./test123.xlsx", n_max = 1, col_names = FALSE))
myDF <- read_excel("./test123.xlsx", skip = 3, col_names = myCols)
```

**Output**

```
  indicator_name         M2   GDP
  <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl>
1 2018-01-01 00:00:00  6.71  8.17
2 2018-01-02 00:00:00  6.79  8.19
3 2018-01-03 00:00:00  6.77  8.21
4 2018-01-04 00:00:00  6.73  8.20
5 2018-01-05 00:00:00  6.67  8.20
6 2018-01-06 00:00:00  6.62  8.21
7 2018-01-07 00:00:00  6.62  8.21
8 2018-01-08 00:00:00  6.64  8.22
9 2018-01-09 00:00:00  6.64  8.22
```

If you have the first column name blank, then you could replace the `NA` in the column names before reading in the data.

```
library(tidyverse)

myCols <- read_excel("./test123.xlsx", n_max = 2, col_names = FALSE) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~replace_na(., "indicator_name"))) %>% 
  as.character()
myDF <- read_excel("./test123.xlsx", skip = 3, col_names = myCols)
```

**Benchmark**

In this instant, it looks like it would still be faster to just filter out the rows after reading them in.

[image]

```
bm <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(filter_before = {myCols <- as.character(read_excel("./test123.xlsx", n_max = 1, col_names = FALSE));
myDF <- read_excel("./test123.xlsx", skip = 3, col_names = myCols)},
filter_after = {myDF2 <- read_excel("./test123.xlsx");
myDF2 <- myDF2[-c(1:2),]},
times = 1000)
autoplot(bm)
```

Comment: It works, thanks for your help again, btw I found that when `indicator_name` cell is filled with `NA`, then I'll get `Error: Sheet 1 has 176 columns (176 unskipped), but col_names has length 175`.

Comment: @ahbon That seems like a pretty common scenario with excel files. I just added an additional part that you could fix the `NA` in the names, before reading in the excel so that you have the correct number of column names. I also added a benchmark as I was curious if it was quicker to just filter these rows after the fact.

Comment: Many thanks for your very detailed solutions and explanations.