# How to read a csv in R with a row above the headers

Tags: r, csv

I'm having trouble reading a csv into R where the first row contains an entry in A1 (as you would open it in excel / google sheets) and the headers are contained in the second row (B1, B2, etc...).

Of course, I can open the csv elsewhere and delete that first row but I can't seem to get R to play ball. With the deleted row, R reads it fine with read.csv(...), but it can't be read otherwise.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

[the data set is here if anyone isn't sure what I mean](https://www.cryptodatadownload.com/cdd/Binance_BTCUSDT_1h.csv)

Comment: Use `read.csv("myFile",  skip=1)`

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860071/read-csv-header-on-first-line-skip-second-line/15860268